R - Using robustrao package - constructing dataset
for a university project i'm interested in measured interdisciplinarity between a set of scientific articles.
I planned on using the R package Robustrao (documentation  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustrao/robustrao.pdf)
In order to use this package i have to construct one matrix containing the similarity between scientifics disciplines and a dataframe with my articles and their cited disciplines ( exemples can be found in the robustrao github linked further down)
I'm having trouble constructing the matrix, for one i seem to have a data table instead of matrix  altough i used did use " matrix"  and all the data was entenred correctly.  I have no past experience nor knwoledge of R it's kind of a one time usage for me.
Here is what i wrote :
donnees <- read.csv("data1.csv", sep = ";", header = FALSE)
if (dim(donnees)[1] != 254 | dim(donnees)[2] != 254) {
  stop("Les dimensions des données ne correspondent pas à 254 x 254.")
}
noms_colonnes <- readLines("nom_colonnes.txt")
noms_lignes <- noms_colonnes
matrice <- matrix(numeric(), nrow = 254, ncol = 254)
colnames(matrice) <- noms_colonnes
rownames(matrice) <- noms_lignes
matrice <- as.matrix(donnees)
colnames(matrice) <- noms_colonnes
rownames(matrice) <- noms_lignes
print(rownames(matrice))

I was expecting something that looks like the Pubdata1  Rdata files from the package that can be found here :  https://github.com/cran/robustrao/blob/master/data/pubdata1.RData
in essence my matrix is not considered as a  Large Matrix  but as a simple data table ?

Remove unnecessary steps from your code and keep the following (assuming data1.csv doesn't contain colnames) :
donnees <- read.csv("data1.csv", sep = ";", header = FALSE)
matrice <- as.matrix(donnees)
noms_colonnes <- readLines("nom_colonnes.txt")
colnames(matrice) <- noms_colonnes
rownames(matrice) <- noms_colonnes

If you execute class(matrice), console should display [1] "matrix" "array".
Another option to build your matrix :
### Package
library(readr)

### Set the working directory where your data is stored
setwd("C:/Users/your_name/Documents")

### Read the .csv file as a dataframe and import colnames during the process
data <- read_delim("data1.csv",
                   delim = ";", 
                   escape_double = FALSE,
                   col_names = readLines("nom_colonnes.txt"), 
                   trim_ws = TRUE)

### Convert the dataframe to matrix
similarity=as.matrix(data)
### Add the rownames
rownames(similarity)<-colnames(data)

### Check the dimension of the matrix
if(reduce(dim(similarity), `/`)!=1) {
  print("Warning, matrix is not square")
} else{
  print("All set !")
}

